# Starting AWS t2.micro instance using python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am having three instances in AWS. I have to start each instance by logging into the account and then start it manually. I want to start it using python by just running a script so that I don't need to login to the AWS account and start the service manually. Here are my instance types.

Is there any way I could do it? I am new to AWS so not finding a way to do it.

[image: ws]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest method would be to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-11111 i-2222 i-3333
```

If you have not previously used the AWS CLI, you will first need to run `aws configure` and provide your IAM User credentials (Access Key + Secret Key).

You can also use a Python script to do this, using the boto3 SDK and the [`start_instances()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.start_instances) command.

Comment: while using boto3 sdk, do I need to use AWS cli or can directly use python?

Comment: you can do both. use boto3 or the aws cli

Comment: The AWS CLI is actually a Python program that uses boto underneath. You can certainly write your own Python script to do this _OR_ you can use the AWS CLI. For such a simple task as starting a few instances, I'd recommend using the AWS CLI command. More complex tasks are best done in a language (such as Python) -- for example, iterating through instances and performing tasks on each instance.